# SharePoint 2007 Error - some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply

Tags: error, caml-query, list-item

Im working with an application on SharePoint 2007, I encountered an issue where the list item unable to view.

It hit error 1309 "Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries"

In addition, how can get to know the SQL query structure? how the SQL statement was nested too deeply.

how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Does your list have workflows attached? May be the workflow history list is creating the problem for you too.

Its kind of a known issue in SharePoint 2007 if its workflow problem. Read [this article](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rhepworth/post/2008/07/03/workflow-history-and-sql-error.aspx) for a clear understanding.

And [another update](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rhepworth/post/2008/08/28/workflow-and-sql-error-part-3.aspx) for this issue is that it might occur for only sites having 'Publishing feature' enabled. (Note: its the *site feature* and not the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure *site collection feature*).